# Options for backups, restoring, and staging?

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation, database

What are some options for Backing Up & Restoring Joomla! instances? Preferably ones suitable for staging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/). Very easy to use and free.

Comment: I second this. Not sure how it can integrate with staging systems, but the pro version of akeeba also lets you get the pro version of Kickstart and that one lets you literally suck backups from another site or even S3. It's very powerful for moving sites around.

Comment: Don't forget the "[UNiTE](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-unite.html)" CLI which is included in the pro subscription.

Answer (score 2):

While Akeeba Backup is without doubt the most popular backup solution, I would like to add that there are also other solutions. You can get a list of them at JED:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup